# Create a windows form on top of Excel workbook but have keyboard input still go into Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, vsto

When a user clicks on a certain cell in Excel, I create a new windows form. Then I use the following commands to put the form on top.

```
FormName.TopMost = True
FormName.TopMost = False
```

When I do this, the windows form steals keyboard input focus from the Excel Application. I still want keyboard input to go into the Excel application. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the forms ShowModal property to False. This will allow the form to float but allow you to select cells, etc. underneath.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (C# but you can easily translate):
(`TOOLWINDOW` is just for fun.)

```
        Form f = new Form2();
        f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        f.Location = new Point(x, y);
        f.Show(new SimpleWindow { Handle = (IntPtr) excelApp.Hwnd } );

   class SimpleWindow : IWin32Window {
       public IntPtr Handle { get; set; }
   }

   public class Form2 : Form {
       private const int WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080;
       protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
           get {
               var cp = base.CreateParams;
               cp.ExStyle = WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;
               return cp;
           }
       }
       protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation {
           get {
               return true;
           }
       }
   }
```